# Searching between two words

Tags: regular-expression, search

I have this string :

```
content htp://ww.mySite.com/image/123kw9ykjm-065n/640/568/25452583.suite />meta property="twitter:suite
```

and I want to get the link to add it in a list;

Here is my function :

```
function MyCodeSource()
    execute "normal! gg" 
    let myList = [] 
    silent! exe '%s/\<https.*suite/\=add(myList, submatch(0))/gn'
    execute "normal! u" 
    echo myList
endfunction
```

The result is :

```
htp://ww.mySite.com/image/123kw9ykjm-065n/640/568/25452583.suite />meta property="twitter:suite
```

instead of :

```
htp://ww.mySite.com/image/123kw9ykjm-065n/640/568/25452583.suite
```

Can you help me to get this link alone, please?

Comment: make your regexp non-greedy (`:h non-greedy`) -- `https.\{-}suite`.

Comment: btw, question title is a bit of misleading, there is nothing in description that uses "between two words"

Comment: Fyi, execute isnt necessary for ex commands like normal and substitute. Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that it's matching all the way to the *last* occurrence of the pattern `suite` on the line.

To solve that, you can either use a non-greedy multi or you can restrict your match to non-whitespace characters only.

A non-greedy multi such as [`\{-}`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%7B-) would solve your issue:

> `\{-}` matches 0 or more of the preceding atom, as few as possible.

This would match only until the *first* occurrence of `suite` in the line:

```
/\<https.\{-}suite
```

Another approach is to use [`\S`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5CS) instead of `.` in your match, to match on non-whitespace characters only.

```
/\<https\S*suite
```

That would prevent the regex from going past the whitespace coming after the URL, which would also solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use \ze after suite, like this:

```
silent! exe '%s/\<https.*suite\ze/\=add(myList, submatch(0))/gn'
```

which will set the end of the match at that position.

See:

```
:help /\ze
```

Comment: This will not work, it won't change the fact that `.*` is still greedy. And `\ze` at the end of the pattern doesn't change much, that's typically the end of the match already.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I write : ```/\<https.*suite\>\ze``` , I have always ```/>meta property="twitter:suite```

Comment: Here is the solution : ```/\<https.\{-}suite\>\ze``` Thank you very much.

Comment: silent and execute aren't needed here